# ND4J: Why random numbers are different with even when specified same seed?

Tags: dl4j, nd4j

I want to generate same sent of random number when a *fixed* seed is given. For that, I have found some classes from **nd4j** documentation. But the generated random number is different. What can be the reason and how to achieve same set of random numbers as default random generator of java yields?

```
        java.util.Random origRand = new java.util.Random();
        org.nd4j.linalg.api.rng.DefaultRandom nd4jRand = Nd4j.getRandom();
        org.nd4j.linalg.api.rng.DefaultRandom nd4jRand2 = new DefaultRandom();

        origRand.setSeed(givenSeed);
        nd4jRand.setSeed(givenSeed);
        nd4jRand2.setSeed(givenSeed);

        System.out.println(origRand.nextFloat()+"\t"+origRand2.nextFloat()+"\t"+nd4jRand.nextFloat()+"\t"+nd4jRand2.nextFloat());

//output:  0.73043025   0.3941323   0.7713206
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no way existing way to generate the same numbers as Java RNG returns. Nd4j and Java use different algorithms for random numbers generation.